# Strip pointer from void* for use in unique_ptr using statement?

Tags: c++, winapi, handle, void-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ program that uses some functions and datastructures from the Win32 API and Wincrypt:

```
#include <memory>
using std::unique_ptr;

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>

using CERTSTORE_ptr = unique_ptr<CERTSTORE, decltype(&:: CertCloseStore)>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile it, I get errors at the `using CERTSTORE_ptr ...` line. The errors:

```
test.cpp(18): error C2873: 'CERTSTORE_ptr' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
test\certstoreexporttest.cpp(18): error C2513: 'int' : no variable declared before '='
test\certstoreexporttest.cpp(18): error C2065: 'CERTSTORE' : undeclared identifier
...
```

The problem appears to be with `CERTSTORE` and `HCERTSTORE`, which is typedef'd as:

```
typedef void *HCERTSTORE;
```

How do I declare the using statement so I can enjoy the automatic cleanup? (I'm trying to avoid the `__try\__finally`).

Or is this simply the wrong approach and should be abandoned? (I'm ready to go back to `__try\__finally` so I can finish up this test program).

Comment: `'CERTSTORE' : undeclared identifier` Start with that...

Comment: Type aliases are only supported in VS2013. I don't think `CERTSTORE` is a type (as opposed to `HCERTSTORE`), and I'm not sure if it's possible to beat `unique_ptr` into submission for your purpose. It should be quite easy to write your own RAII wrapper, though.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but why don't you just use a typedef?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I abandoned the strategy. I went back to `__try/__finally` since it was a test program. It just was not a good fit.